# Checking if MovieClip is on top of another

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, movieclip

I'm generating a number of MovieClips and am putting them on the container on random positions... However, it sometimes happens that one MC is almost directly on top of another...

I could solve this easily if I could somehow check if the random-generated x and y are on top of any other MCs x and y...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`hitTestPoint()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTestPoint()) can tell you if your object is over a specific point:

```
if (myMovieClip.hitTestPoint(myX,myY) == true)
{
   trace("hit detected");
}
```

You can also use [`hitTestObject()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTestObject()) to detect a collision or overlap with another movieClip:

```
if (myMovieClip1.hitTestObject(myMovieClip2) == true)
{
   trace("hit detected");
}
```